# Verificar se é uma lista em c#

Tags: c#

Tenho um método, aonde vou receber um objeto de qualquer Class, e uma das suas propriedades pode ser uma Lista que pode ser de um objeto específico ou string, int, decimal e etc.

Minha pergunta é: Como identificar se foi recebido uma lista sendo de qualquer tipo e percorrer suas propriedades levando em consideração que a lista pode ser ou não uma lista de objetos.

Da forma atual, é possível só identificar se a lista é do mesmo tipo do objeto da classe. Se a lista for de outra classe ou se for string...int etc, da como false sempre na comparacao.

```
public bool PropriedadesObjetoDefault<T>(T obj)
    {

        PropertyInfo[] propriedades = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

        int totalPropriedades = propriedades.Count();
        int contador = 0;

        foreach (PropertyInfo propriedade in propriedades)
        {
            this.VerificaTipoPropriedade(propriedade, ref obj, ref contador);

        }

        if (contador == totalPropriedades)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

private bool VerificaTipoPropriedade<T>(PropertyInfo propriedade, ref T obj, ref int contador)
    {
        Type tipo = propriedade.PropertyType;

        var valor = propriedade.GetValue(obj);


        if (tipo.Equals(typeof(bool)))
        {
            if (valor.Equals(default(bool)))
                contador++;

        }
        else if (tipo.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
        {
            if (valor.Equals(default(DateTime)))
                contador++;

        }
        else if (tipo.Equals(typeof(List<T>)))
        {
            // percorrer entre os objetos 

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Adicione seu código à pergunta pra que agente possa te ajudar amigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode verificar se o tipo implementa o `ICollection<>`, uma vez que essa interface é necessária em todas as classes colecionáveis.

Coloque essa verificação acima de todos as outras verificações:

```
if (valor is ICollection) { // vai direto pelo valor, isso se ele for um object
    foreach(var item in (valor as ICollection<object>)) {
         Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

A palavra `is` verifica se o primeiro valor é implementado da classe do segundo valor.

Sintaxe:

```
bool (<valor ou tipo> is <tipo>)
```

---

```
private bool VerificaTipoPropriedade<T>(PropertyInfo propriedade, ref T obj, ref int contador)
{
    Type tipo = propriedade.PropertyType;

    var valor = propriedade.GetValue(obj);

    if (valor is ICollection) { // vai direto pelo valor, isso se ele for um object
        foreach(var item in (valor as ICollection<object>) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        return;
    }
    else if (tipo.Equals(typeof(bool)))
    {
        if (valor.Equals(default(bool)))
            contador++;

    }
    else if (tipo.Equals(typeof(DateTime)))
    {
        if (valor.Equals(default(DateTime)))
            contador++;

    }
    else if (tipo.Equals(typeof(List<T>)))
    {
        // percorrer entre os objetos 

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo !...muito obrigado!!